# Not getting result printed in browser for hitting codeigniter web service

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I recently uploaded or installed codeigniter on Cpanel and this is my first function or first service that i made and i am not getting the result printed.
the email annd password is there in database and still it is showing error.

http://www.liontekusa.com/con_college/login?email=exaple.com&password=123456.

The above is my url

The below is the error it.
[image]
No input file specified.

Comment: Can you share your code

Answer (score 2):

Please follow some step:

1. if you didn't remove index.php from config then you must have to use index.php then your controller name.
   example : [http://www.liontekusa.com/index.php/con_college/login]
2. your controller file first letter should be capital. n class name also